# Search based on value from a dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, razor

I have a project which acts as a web bookstore. I have implemented a search which at the moment, only searches books by author. What I'd like to do is enable search by author/title/something else.

I have a general idea on how I think this could work, but I'm missing some pieces which is why I'm asking for advice here.

Here is what I think might be a good approach:

- Have a dropdown selector in the view in which I can specify searching by author / booktitle
- That would get passed from the view to the controller and I would be able to search by the passed in value (author / booktitle).

I'd like to know how is it possible to implement my approach, as well as discuss 
 different ideas which might work as well. Thank you for your time.

Below is the code in the controller which returns books by author that I search for, pretty simple.

```
 public IActionResult Index(string searchString)
       {
        bool hasSearchResults = false;
        var model = _bookstoreData.GetAll();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            model = model.Where(s => s.Author.Contains(searchString));
            hasSearchResults = true;
        }
        return hasSearchResults ? View("SearchResult", model) : View(model);
       }
```

This is the matching view:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
            <div class="container searchBar">
                <div class="container searchBar">
                    <input type="text" name="searchString" class="form-control" placeholder="Search books by title, author...">
                    <input type="hidden" />
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Try using an IF statement and add two checks for both author and title `model = model.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));` You could quite easily check for many different things about a book by using a loop or switch statement. If you are entering both the author and title into the same search box then you need to use a bit of smart logic and first find all books by the matching author first (by doing a partial string match of all words in the search field), and then do another match all of that authors books by title (Also a partial string match).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think writing a little search `Func<>` would be a nice way to achieve the search across multiple properties in a model. It may use `Reflection` to make it more generic but we are going to try to keep it simple.

Assuming your **Book** model looks like this

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
}
```

Now lets create a simple `Regex`

```
private bool IsMatch(string input, string pattern)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

We are going to reuse this function in the search `Func<>` that we are going to create and use if to filter books.
A `Func<>` is basically like a function call that can have inputs and return values.

Let's look our search func

```
Func<Book, bool> searchFunc = (book) =>
{
    string query = $"({q})";

    if (IsMatch(book.Title, query) || IsMatch(book.Author, query) || 
        IsMatch(book.ISBN, query)
        {
           return true;
        }
    return false;
};
```

Let's **finally** put it together in our index action

```
public IActionResult Index(string q)
{
    Func<Book, bool> searchFunc = (book) =>
    {
        string query = $"({q})";

        if (IsMatch(book.Title, query) || IsMatch(book.Author, query) || 
            IsMatch(book.ISBN, query))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
    var books = _bookstoreData.GetAll()
                              .Where(searchFunc)
                              .ToList();
    return books.Count > 0 ? View("SearchResult", books) : View(books);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind, thank you! Where would you use Reflection in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyonee is interested, here is the code I ended up with after using what @machariadev suggested.

If search string is empty, all books are shown, if there is a search string, view with the appropriate results is shown.

```
 public IActionResult Index(string searchString)
    {
        bool hasSearchResults = false;
        var model = _bookstoreData.GetAll();

        Func<Book, bool> searchFunc = (book) =>
        {
            string query = $"({searchString})";
            if (IsMatch(book.Title, query) || IsMatch(book.Author, query))
                return true;
            return false;
        };

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            model = model.Where(searchFunc).ToList();
            hasSearchResults = true;
        }

        return hasSearchResults ? View("SearchResult", model) : View(model);
    }
```